# What exactly is the geodesic flow?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, geodesic

I understand what a geodesic is, but I'm struggling to understand the meaning of the geodesic flow (as defined e.g. by *Do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry*, page 63).

I can state my confusion in two different ways:

## 1)

Do Carmo writes:

[image]

Why does a geodesic $\gamma$ uniquely define a vector field *on an open subset*? In other words, why are the values of the vector fields uniquely defined on those points that are not on the geodesic $\gamma$?

## 2)

In local coordinates, the geodesic flow is defined as the solution to the ordinary differential equation

$$
\tag{1}\frac{d^2 x_k}{dt^2}+\sum_{i,j}\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{dx_i}{dt}\frac{dx_j}{dt}=0
$$

For the solution to be unique on $TM$ (or on an open subset), we need some boundary condition. The only boundary condition I can see is a given geodesic $\gamma(t)$.

What are the boundary conditions for this ODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea behind the approach Do Carmo takes is to interpret a curve $(\gamma(t), \gamma'(t))$ where $\gamma \colon [a,b] \rightarrow M$ is a geodesic in $M$ as an integral curve of a globally defined vector field $G$ on $TM$. Once you do that, in order to show the existence of a geodesic $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$ (with $v \in T_pM$) you can take an integral curve $\beta \colon (a,b) \rightarrow TM$ of $G$ with $\beta(0) = (p,v)$ and then the projection $\gamma := \pi \circ \beta$ of $\beta$ to $M$ will be a geodesic which satisfies the initial conditions $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$.

The uniqueness of geodesics will follow from the uniqueness of integral curves of the vector field $G$, once a starting point $(p,v) \in TM$ is specified. There is no need to impose boundary conditions (and in general, an ODE with boundary conditions might have no solutions satisfying arbitrary boundary conditions), only initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still at the same problem. Yes, the geodesic defines the vector field **on the image of the geodesic**, i.e. on the points $p$ that are **on** the geodesic. But take a point $\bar p$ which is **not** on the geodesic. How is the vector field at $\bar p$ defined?

Comment: @AndyMiles: It's not that a specific geodesic defines the vector field on the image of the geodesic, it's the geodesic **equation** which defines a vector field on $TM$ according to the formula given in Do Carmo.

Comment: Getting more confused. Are we talking about one vector field for *all* geodesics, or one vector field for *each* geodesic? In other words, does Do Carmo's lemma say *"for each given geodesic $\gamma$, there is a unique vector field such that..."*, or does it say *"there is one unique vector field such that for each geodesic $\gamma$ ..."*? Is it $\forall\gamma\exists G$ or $\exists G\forall\gamma$?

Comment: @AndyMiles: The point is that there is one vector field whose integrals curves gives you **all** the geodesics. If you prefer to think about it in another way, assume first that **all** geodesics exist for a short time. For each $(p,v) \in TM$, consider a geodesic $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Then $\beta(t) = (\gamma(t), \gamma'(t))$ is a curve in $TM$ and you want to find a vector field $G$ which is globally defined on $TM$ such that $\beta$ is an integral curve of $G$.

Comment: That is, $\beta'(t) = G(\beta(t))$ so $G$ is determined on the image of $\beta$. Since we assumed that all geodesics exist, we know the value of $G$ at all the points of $TM$ and it is well-defined because a geodesic, being a solution of a second order ODE, should be determined uniquely by the initial values. Now, in order to prove existence and uniqueness of geodesics, the logic is reversed. We construct $G$ explicitly and then the projection of the integral curves of $G$ will be geodesics.

Comment: Uh, when you're saying "vector field defined on TM", do you mean a vector field on the bundle of vector fields? So for each *pair* $(p,v)$ it assigns a "vector-vector" $(\dot p,\dot v)$, right? I think my problem is that I thought of it as just a vector field on $M$, instead of one on $TM$.

Comment: @AndyMiles: Yeah, more precisely, a vector field on the bundle of tangent vectors, not vector fields. So yes, for each pair $(p,v) \in TM$ it assigns a tangent vector in $T_{(p,v)}(TM)$. There's no chance to get a vector field on $M$ because a geodesic is not determined uniquely but the initial position, only by the initial position and velocity. That's why we need to lift everything to $TM$. This is very similar to the trick of reducing a second order equation to a pair of first order equations by introducing a formal variable and another equation.

Comment: Thank you! Such a vector field seems better suited to accommodate for *all* geodesics than just a vector field on $M$ :-)